# making sense of bfs and dfs

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to make sense of the outputs of `bfs` and `dfs`. I have a mst of some 3d point clouds which i am performing registration on, from which I want to derive a sequence of pairwise registrations along the edges. These pairwise registrations rely on previous registrations starting from a seed subsample.

As such I am trying to get an ordered list of edges from a seed edge (or vertex) so that pairwise comparisons can be properly propagated through the tree.

I have been trying to use `bfs` and `dfs` but can't make sense of the outputs to construct my ordered edge list.

library(igraph)

```
edges <- data.frame(
  from = c(2,14,8,17,11,16,14,12,14,13,14,16,13,19,15,23,21,21,22,23,20,22),
  to   = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,16,18,18,18,19,20),
 dist  = c(1.7479352,4.1400081,0.9064689,0.5735992,0.7550112,1.3880579,1.6968155,
          1.0064647,2.7119138,2.4033570,3.7260517,1.1921137,2.0857017,0.2903520,
          1.4191598,0.6111305,1.5752026,1.3102844,0.5070067,0.6522495,0.3172266,
          0.6373009
))
g <- graph.data.frame(edges, directed = F)
plot(g)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5xd0.png

I then choose the seed as the pair with the largest distance between them and run `bfs` or `dfs`

```
seedPair <- edges[which.max(edges[,3]),1:2]
> seedPair
  row col
2  14   1
```

For simplicity I just directly input vertex 14 as the root

```
path <- bfs(g, root = 14, father = T, rank = T)
> path
$root
[1] 14

$mode
[1] "out"

$order
+ 23/23 vertices, named, from 192f5fa:
 [1] 20 19 22 10 18 23 21 13 16 6  9  8  3  2  11 17 1  15 14 4  5  7  12

$rank
 2 14  8 17 11 16 12 13 19 15 23 21 22 20  1  3  4  5  6  7  9 10 18 
14 19 12 16 15  9 23  8  2 18  6  7  3  1 17 13 20 21 10 22 11  4  5 

$father
+ 23/23 vertices, named, from 192f5fa:
 [1] 2  14 8  17 11 16 12 13 19 15 23 21 22 20 1  3  4  5  6  7  9  10 18
```

```
path <- dfs(g, root = 14, order = T, order.out = T, father = T)
> path
$root
[1] 13

$mode
[1] "out"

$order
+ 23/23 vertices, named, from 192f5fa:
 [1] 20 19 10 22 18 23 13 6  9  21 16 8  2  17 1  14 4  5  12 7  3  11 15

$order.out
+ 23/23 vertices, named, from 192f5fa:
 [1] 10 19 6  9  13 23 17 4  12 5  7  14 1  2  8  15 11 3  16 21 18 22 20

$father
+ 23/23 vertices, named, from 192f5fa:
 [1] 2  14 8  17 11 16 12 13 19 15 23 21 22 20 1  3  4  5  6  7  9  10 18

$dist
NULL

$neimode
[1] "out"
```

Looking at the mst, neither of these outputs make sense to me if I'm starting at vertex 14. `dfs` is more intuitive to me and is easier to follow the edge sequence, but I also don't understand why its returning the root as 13, but then actually starting at node 20.

I would very appreciate any help understanding these outputs, or alternative approaches to getting an ordered edge sequence from a seed location. Thanks!

Comment: - Regarding the root. When I ran a bfs with start on vertex one, I got back $root = 0. This is probably a bug, for example the numbering in the original c library running from zero, instead of 1 as in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Addendum**, include vertex metadata.

```
vertices <- seq(max(edges[1:2]))
g <- graph.data.frame(edges, vertices, directed = F)
```

or create an unnamed graph

```
ug <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(edges[,1:2]), directed = FALSE)
E(g)$dist   <- edges[,3]
```

When I run.

```
edges <- data.frame(
  from = c(2,14,8,17,11,16,14,12,14,13,14,16,13,19,15,23,21,21,22,23,20,22),
  to   = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,16,18,18,18,19,20),
 dist  = c(1.7479352,4.1400081,0.9064689,0.5735992,0.7550112,1.3880579,1.6968155,
          1.0064647,2.7119138,2.4033570,3.7260517,1.1921137,2.0857017,0.2903520,
          1.4191598,0.6111305,1.5752026,1.3102844,0.5070067,0.6522495,0.3172266,
          0.6373009
))
g <- graph.data.frame(edges, directed = F)
V(g)$name <- seq(vcount(g))   # ! Reset node n to "n".
>g
```

The resulting graph is.

```
IGRAPH 902edcd UN-- 23 22 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), dist (e/n)
+ edges from 902edcd (vertex names):
 [1] 1 --15 2 --15 1 --3  1 --4  5 --16 6 --16 2 --17 7 --18 2 --18 8 --19 2 --20 3 --6  8 --21 9 --22 5 --10 8 --11
[17] 6 --12 12--23 13--23 11--23 9 --14 13--14
```

Running dfs().

```
path <- dfs(g, root = 14, order = TRUE, order.out = TRUE, father = TRUE)
>path
```

This gives.

```
$root
[1] 13

$mode
[1] "out"

$order
+ 23/23 vertices, named, from e6365e8:
 [1] 14 9  22 13 23 11 8  19 21 12 6  3  1  4  15 2  17 18 7  20 16 5  10

$order.out
+ 23/23 vertices, named, from e6365e8:
 [1] 22 9  19 21 8  11 4  17 7  18 20 2  15 1  3  10 5  16 6  12 23 13 14

$father
+ 23/23 vertices, named, from e6365e8:
 [1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23

$dist
NULL

$neimode
[1] "out"
```

Which is different then the output in the question, The reason being the statement `V(g)$name <- seq(vcount(g))`. Without this statement V(g)[14] is 20, due to the data frame logic.

The following code implements a simple dfs() search.

```
visit <- function(g, v){
  if (length(visited)>0L && !visited[v]) {
    cat("order: ", v, '\n')
    visited[v] <<- 1L
    for (w in V(g)[.nei(v)]) visit(g, w)
    cat("order.out: ", v, '\n')
    }
  }
 
# Call dfs()
  visited <- rep(0L, gorder(g))
  visit(g, 14)
```

According to the docs, $order.out is a numeric vector, the vertex ids, in the order of the `completion` of their subtree. $order shows the vertex ids at entry.

Try a simple graph, like make_ring(10), to check the logic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: AHH that makes sense. I didn't consider that igraph was treating the vertex IDs as strings. I added the line `seed <- which(V(g)$name == as.character(seedPair[1]))` to convert to the DF index:

Comment: @Blake, Treating the vertex IDs as a symbolic edge list is indeed the cause of the problem. I have edited my answer to show how vertex metadata can be included. Type >`?graph_data_frame`, or `?as_data_frame` for further reading.

Comment: Thanks so much, I really appreciate the guidance.